# Show * while I input (Hide/mask input)

Tags: c++, windows, masking

I am in the process of getting **password** as input.
I have gone through various examples but they either used while loop or SETCONSOLE method. Both had issues.
Implementing while loop printed 1 * before I even entered a char. The other method used echo to **HIDE** the characters while I typed whereas I want to be printed. I would appreciate helping me masking my input with a * using SETCONSOLE method. I would be greatly obliged. The code's attached !

```
 void signup(){
    gotoxy(10, 10);
    string n, p1,p2;
     cout << "Enter your username: " << endl; // TEST if username already       exists
gotoxy(31, 10);
cin >> n;
lp:
gotoxy(10, 11);
cout << "Enter your password: " << endl; // TEST if username already exists
gotoxy(31, 11);

getline(cin, p1);
system("cls");
gotoxy(10, 10);
cout << "Re-Enter your password to confirm: " << endl; // TEST if username already exists
gotoxy(45, 10);
getline(cin, p2);



if (p2!=p1)
{
    system("cls");
    gotoxy(10, 10);
    cout << "Passwords donot match! Please enter again!";
        goto lp;
}
```

}

Comment: Please specify which operating system you are targeting, as well as provide a short code snippet of what you've already tried.

Comment: What's a SETCONSOLE method?

Comment: @Raw N DWORD  mode;
  HANDLE hConIn = GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );
  GetConsoleMode( hConIn, &mode );
  mode = on
       ? (mode |   ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT )
       : (mode & ~(ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT));
  SetConsoleMode( hConIn, mode );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a simple example using `getch`. YES it c method, not c++, but it is very efficient.

It can be extended to block spaces, tabs, etc.

Also see the comments in the code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;


int main(){ 
    string res;
    char c;
    cout<<"enter password:";
    do{
        c = getch();
        switch(c){
        case 0://special keys. like: arrows, f1-12 etc.
            getch();//just ignore also the next character.
            break;
        case 13://enter
            cout<<endl;
            break;
        case 8://backspace
            if(res.length()>0){
                res.erase(res.end()-1); //remove last character from string
                cout<<c<<' '<<c;//go back, write space over the character and back again.
            }
            break;
        default://regular ascii
            res += c;//add to string
            cout<<'*';//print `*`
            break;
        }
    }while(c!=13);
    //print result:
    cout<<res<<endl;
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Though I had to clear the string by using clear() just before the loop if the passwords didnt match but it DID solve the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Although the other method if explained will be helpful too :)

Comment: it just simplified the password typing, you can put it in some `getpassword`  method and call it for each password input.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `getch()` (`#include <conio.h>`) to read a character without its being echoed to the screen. Then when you've validated that it's a character you want to accept, you can print out a `*` at the correct position.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can try this.
The password input has a limit tho but the masking works fine

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

void mask(int i);

int main()
{
    int i;
    char a[10];
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        cout << "Enter password : ";
        mask(i);
        a[i] = getch();
        clrscr();
    }
    cout << "Password set" << endl;
    cout << "Forgot password, Press 0 : ";
    cin >> i;
    if (i==0)
        cout << a;
    else 
        return 0;
}

void mask(int i) {
    for(int k=1; k<=i; k++)
        cout << "*";
}
```